# How to install GCC and/or apt on embedded linux Raspberry Pi

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, yocto

I have a pre-configured linux distro on a raspberry pi (used for a bitcoin miner).
The problem is that this distro is very minimal, only has busybox for basic commands. It doesn't have a package manager and it doesn't even have a gcc compiler. So my target is to install a gcc compiler on it so I can go further and install other software.

So I'm basically limited to these commands from busybox:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ls /bin
addgroup             fgrep                ping6
adduser              grep                 ps
ash                  gunzip               pwd
busybox              gzip                 rm
cat                  hostname             rmdir
chattr               ip                   sed
chgrp                kill                 sh
chmod                ln                   sleep
chown                login                stty
cp                   ls                   su
cpio                 mkdir                sync
date                 mknod                tar
dd                   mktemp               tinylogin
delgroup             more                 touch
deluser              mount                true
df                   mountpoint           umount
dmesg                mountpoint.sysvinit  uname
dnsdomainname        mv                   usleep
dumpkmap             netstat              vi
echo                 pidof                zcat
egrep                pidof.sysvinit
false                ping
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -l /usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 [ -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 [[ -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 ar -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 awk -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 basename -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 bunzip2 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 bzcat -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        302368 Apr 22  2014 cgminer
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          4179 Apr 18  2014 cherryd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            17 Feb 21 14:30 chvt -> /usr/bin/chvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6860 Feb 19 12:23 chvt.kbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 clear -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 cmp -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4304 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-check
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           218 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-format
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4796 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-packer
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          3968 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-unpacker
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           990 Mar 11 03:18 create-cracklib-dict
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        135908 Mar 28 12:33 curl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 cut -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            23 Feb 21 14:37 dbclient -> /usr/sbin/dropbearmulti
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 dc -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         13372 Feb 19 12:24 ddcmon
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:30 deallocvt -> /usr/bin/deallocvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7352 Feb 19 12:23 deallocvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         64815 Feb 19 12:24 decode-dimms
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6104 Feb 19 12:24 decode-edid
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          5650 Feb 19 12:24 decode-vaio
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 diff -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 dirname -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 du -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         58744 Feb 19 12:23 dumpkeys
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 dumpleases -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           287 Feb 19 12:24 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           295 Feb 19 12:24 easy_install-2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 env -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 expr -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:30 fgconsole -> /usr/bin/fgconsole.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7460 Feb 19 12:23 fgconsole.kbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 find -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 flock -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 free -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 fuser -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7736 Feb 19 12:23 getkeycodes
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 groups -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 head -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 hexdump -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 id -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7936 Feb 19 12:23 kbd_mode
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8492 Feb 19 12:23 kbdrate
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 killall -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 last -> /usr/bin/last.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14048 Feb 19 12:15 last.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             4 Feb 21 14:32 lastb -> last
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 less -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         85348 Feb 19 12:23 loadkeys
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         19952 Feb 19 12:23 loadunimap
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 logger -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 logname -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1229 Feb 19 12:24 mako-render
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         15000 Feb 19 12:23 mapscrn
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 md5sum -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 mesg -> /usr/bin/mesg.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6532 Feb 19 12:15 mesg.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 microcom -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 mkfifo -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         18056 Mar 11 03:20 mkhomedir_helper
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nc -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nohup -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nslookup -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 od -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        488032 Apr 18  2014 openssl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Feb 21 14:30 openvt -> /usr/bin/openvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         12084 Feb 19 12:23 openvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9852 Mar 11 03:20 pam_tally
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9872 Mar 11 03:20 pam_tally2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9904 Mar 11 03:20 pam_timestamp_check
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:30 passwd -> /bin/tinylogin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 patch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 Feb 21 14:37 perl -> perl5.14.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8768 Feb 19 12:25 perl5.14.3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 printf -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfaddtable -> psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfgettable -> psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfstriptable -> psfxtable
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         16844 Feb 19 12:23 psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            28 Feb 21 14:32 psplash -> /usr/bin/psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         50484 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-default
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        113760 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          5516 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-write
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Feb 21 14:37 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:37 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:37 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            16 Feb 21 14:37 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6268 Apr 18  2014 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1618 Feb 19 12:19 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 readlink -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 realpath -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 renice -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 reset -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         11882 Feb 19 12:24 rpio
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         16597 Feb 19 12:24 rpio-curses
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 run-parts -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            23 Feb 21 14:37 scp -> /usr/sbin/dropbearmulti
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar 11 02:22 screen -> screen-4.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        312200 Mar 11 02:22 screen-4.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 seq -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         33868 Feb 19 12:23 setfont
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7276 Feb 19 12:23 setkeycodes
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8768 Feb 19 12:23 setleds
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6900 Feb 19 12:23 setmetamode
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14260 Feb 19 12:23 showconsolefont
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         10020 Feb 19 12:23 showkey
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 sort -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         49100 Feb 19 12:13 sqlite3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            23 Feb 21 14:37 ssh -> /usr/sbin/dropbearmulti
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 stat -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 strings -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tail -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tee -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 telnet -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 test -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tftp -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 time -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 top -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tr -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 traceroute -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tty -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        137588 Feb 19 12:23 udevadm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2425 Feb 19 12:23 unicode_start
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           363 Feb 19 12:23 unicode_stop
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 uniq -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         26424 Mar 11 03:20 unix_chkpwd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         26412 Mar 11 03:20 unix_update
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 unzip -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4267 Feb 19 12:09 update-alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 uptime -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 users -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            26 Feb 21 14:32 utmpdump -> /usr/bin/utmpdump.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9568 Feb 19 12:15 utmpdump.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:30 vlock -> /bin/tinylogin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 wall -> /usr/bin/wall.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         10764 Feb 19 12:15 wall.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 watch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 wc -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 wget -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 which -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 who -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 whoami -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 xargs -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 yes -> /bin/busybox
```

What I have tried so far is to download a new busybox from [here](http://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/busybox-armv7l)
which includes more commands, most notably rpm (still lacks dpkg though)

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./busybox-armv7l
BusyBox v1.21.1 (2013-07-08 10:26:30 CDT) multi-call binary.
BusyBox is copyrighted by many authors between 1998-2012.
Licensed under GPLv2. See source distribution for detailed
copyright notices.

Usage: busybox [function [arguments]...]
   or: busybox --list[-full]
   or: busybox --install [-s] [DIR]
   or: function [arguments]...

        BusyBox is a multi-call binary that combines many common Unix
        utilities into a single executable.  Most people will create a
        link to busybox for each function they wish to use and BusyBox
        will act like whatever it was invoked as.

Currently defined functions:
        [, [[, acpid, add-shell, addgroup, adduser, adjtimex, arp, arping, ash, awk, base64,
        basename, beep, blkid, blockdev, bootchartd, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat, bzip2, cal, cat,
        catv, chat, chattr, chgrp, chmod, chown, chpasswd, chpst, chroot, chrt, chvt, cksum,
        clear, cmp, comm, conspy, cp, cpio, crond, crontab, cryptpw, cttyhack, cut, date, dc, dd,
        deallocvt, delgroup, deluser, depmod, devmem, df, dhcprelay, diff, dirname, dmesg, dnsd,
        dnsdomainname, dos2unix, du, dumpkmap, dumpleases, echo, ed, egrep, eject, env, envdir,
        envuidgid, ether-wake, expand, expr, fakeidentd, false, fbset, fbsplash, fdflush,
        fdformat, fdisk, fgconsole, fgrep, find, findfs, flock, fold, free, freeramdisk, fsck,
        fsck.minix, fsync, ftpd, ftpget, ftpput, fuser, getopt, getty, grep, groups, gunzip,
        gzip, halt, hd, hdparm, head, hexdump, hostid, hostname, httpd, hush, hwclock, id,
        ifconfig, ifdown, ifenslave, ifplugd, ifup, inetd, init, insmod, install, ionice, iostat,
        ip, ipaddr, ipcalc, ipcrm, ipcs, iplink, iproute, iprule, iptunnel, kbd_mode, kill,
        killall, killall5, klogd, last, less, linux32, linux64, linuxrc, ln, loadfont, loadkmap,
        logger, login, logname, logread, losetup, lpd, lpq, lpr, ls, lsattr, lsmod, lsof, lspci,
        lsusb, lzcat, lzma, lzop, lzopcat, makedevs, makemime, man, md5sum, mdev, mesg, microcom,
        mkdir, mkdosfs, mke2fs, mkfifo, mkfs.ext2, mkfs.minix, mkfs.vfat, mknod, mkpasswd,
        mkswap, mktemp, modinfo, modprobe, more, mount, mountpoint, mpstat, mt, mv, nameif,
        nanddump, nandwrite, nbd-client, nc, netstat, nice, nmeter, nohup, nslookup, ntpd, od,
        openvt, passwd, patch, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pipe_progress, pivot_root, pkill, pmap,
        popmaildir, poweroff, powertop, printenv, printf, ps, pscan, pstree, pwd, pwdx,
        raidautorun, rdate, rdev, readahead, readlink, readprofile, realpath, reboot, reformime,
        remove-shell, renice, reset, resize, rev, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, rpm, rpm2cpio,
        rtcwake, run-parts, runlevel, runsv, runsvdir, rx, script, scriptreplay, sed, sendmail,
        seq, setarch, setconsole, setfont, setkeycodes, setlogcons, setserial, setsid, setuidgid,
        sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha3sum, sha512sum, showkey, slattach, sleep, smemcap, softlimit,
        sort, split, start-stop-daemon, stat, strings, stty, su, sulogin, sum, sv, svlogd,
        swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd, tac, tail, tar, tcpsvd, tee, telnet,
        telnetd, test, tftp, tftpd, time, timeout, top, touch, tr, traceroute, traceroute6, true,
        tty, ttysize, tunctl, udhcpc, udhcpd, udpsvd, umount, uname, unexpand, uniq, unix2dos,
        unlzma, unlzop, unxz, unzip, uptime, users, usleep, uudecode, uuencode, vconfig, vi,
        vlock, volname, wall, watch, watchdog, wc, wget, which, who, whoami, whois, xargs, xz,
        xzcat, yes, zcat, zcip
```

I have downloaded some gcc rpm's from here
http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=
but for some reason gcc does not execute

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ./busybox-armv7l rpm -i gcc-4.8.2-1.fc20.armv7hl.rpm
root@raspberrypi:~# find / -name gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc
/usr/lib/gcc
/usr/libexec/gcc
/opt/STM/STLinux-2.4/devkit/armv7/target/usr/bin/gcc
/opt/STM/STLinux-2.4/devkit/armv7/target/usr/lib/gcc
/opt/STM/STLinux-2.4/devkit/armv7/target/usr/libexec/gcc
root@raspberrypi:~# cd /usr/bin
root@raspberrypi:/usr/bin# ./gcc
-sh: ./gcc: not found
root@raspberrypi:/usr/bin# ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 [ -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 [[ -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 ar -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        562184 Mar 29 02:30 arm-linux-gnu-cpp
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        562184 Mar 29 02:30 arm-linux-gnu-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        257596 Mar 29 02:30 arm-linux-gnu-gcov
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        622224 Oct 17 10:53 armv7hl-redhat-linux-gnueabi-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 awk -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 basename -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 bunzip2 -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 bzcat -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           224 Oct 17 10:52 c89
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           215 Oct 17 10:52 c99
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             3 Apr 10 21:31 cc -> gcc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        302368 Apr 22  2014 cgminer
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          4179 Apr 18  2014 cherryd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            17 Feb 21 14:30 chvt -> /usr/bin/chvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6860 Feb 19 12:23 chvt.kbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 clear -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 cmp -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4304 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-check
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           218 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-format
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4796 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-packer
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          3968 Mar 11 03:18 cracklib-unpacker
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           990 Mar 11 03:18 create-cracklib-dict
....
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           287 Feb 19 12:24 easy_install
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           295 Feb 19 12:24 easy_install-2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 env -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 expr -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:30 fgconsole -> /usr/bin/fgconsole.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7460 Feb 19 12:23 fgconsole.kbd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 find -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 flock -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 free -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 fuser -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        622224 Oct 17 10:53 gcc
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         25900 Oct 17 10:54 gcc-ar
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         25856 Oct 17 10:53 gcc-nm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         25864 Oct 17 10:54 gcc-ranlib
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        260996 Oct 17 10:54 gcov
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7736 Feb 19 12:23 getkeycodes
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 groups -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 head -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 hexdump -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 id -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7936 Feb 19 12:23 kbd_mode
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8492 Feb 19 12:23 kbdrate
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 killall -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 last -> /usr/bin/last.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14048 Feb 19 12:15 last.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             4 Feb 21 14:32 lastb -> last
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 less -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         85348 Feb 19 12:23 loadkeys
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         19952 Feb 19 12:23 loadunimap
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 logger -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 logname -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1229 Feb 19 12:24 mako-render
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         15000 Feb 19 12:23 mapscrn
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 md5sum -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 mesg -> /usr/bin/mesg.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6532 Feb 19 12:15 mesg.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 microcom -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 mkfifo -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         18056 Mar 11 03:20 mkhomedir_helper
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nc -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nohup -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 nslookup -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 od -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        488032 Apr 18  2014 openssl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            19 Feb 21 14:30 openvt -> /usr/bin/openvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         12084 Feb 19 12:23 openvt.kbd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9852 Mar 11 03:20 pam_tally
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9872 Mar 11 03:20 pam_tally2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9904 Mar 11 03:20 pam_timestamp_check
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:30 passwd -> /bin/tinylogin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 patch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 Feb 21 14:37 perl -> perl5.14.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8768 Feb 19 12:25 perl5.14.3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 printf -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfaddtable -> psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfgettable -> psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:30 psfstriptable -> psfxtable
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         16844 Feb 19 12:23 psfxtable
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            28 Feb 21 14:32 psplash -> /usr/bin/psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         50484 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-default
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        113760 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-raspberrypi
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          5516 Feb 19 12:16 psplash-write
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 Feb 21 14:37 python -> python2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:37 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Feb 21 14:37 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            16 Feb 21 14:37 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6268 Apr 18  2014 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1618 Feb 19 12:19 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 readlink -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 realpath -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 renice -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 reset -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         11882 Feb 19 12:24 rpio
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         16597 Feb 19 12:24 rpio-curses
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 run-parts -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            23 Feb 21 14:37 scp -> /usr/sbin/dropbearmulti
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Mar 11 02:22 screen -> screen-4.0.3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        312200 Mar 11 02:22 screen-4.0.3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 seq -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         33868 Feb 19 12:23 setfont
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          7276 Feb 19 12:23 setkeycodes
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          8768 Feb 19 12:23 setleds
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          6900 Feb 19 12:23 setmetamode
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         14260 Feb 19 12:23 showconsolefont
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         10020 Feb 19 12:23 showkey
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 sort -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         49100 Feb 19 12:13 sqlite3
.....
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 tty -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        137588 Feb 19 12:23 udevadm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          2425 Feb 19 12:23 unicode_start
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           363 Feb 19 12:23 unicode_stop
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 uniq -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         26424 Mar 11 03:20 unix_chkpwd
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         26412 Mar 11 03:20 unix_update
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 unzip -> /bin/busybox
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4267 Feb 19 12:09 update-alternatives
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 uptime -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 users -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            26 Feb 21 14:32 utmpdump -> /usr/bin/utmpdump.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          9568 Feb 19 12:15 utmpdump.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Feb 21 14:30 vlock -> /bin/tinylogin
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Feb 21 14:32 wall -> /usr/bin/wall.sysvinit
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         10764 Feb 19 12:15 wall.sysvinit
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 watch -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 wc -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 wget -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 which -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 who -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 whoami -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 xargs -> /bin/busybox
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Feb 21 14:30 yes -> /bin/busybox
```

Also tried installing apt-rpm to get apt-get, but it misses a shared libary

```
root@raspberrypi:~# apt-get
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/liblua-5.1.so: internal error
```

can someone help me on all this??

Comment: Why dont you use cross compiler?

Comment: I have googled about cross compiling, looks a tricky process though. How would I do it?

Comment: Download CodeSourcery cross compiler. Rest is simple, just like compiling code for you i386 architecture, do compile your code as 'arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc test.c -o test_binary'. Move your binary to raspberry pi and its done.

Comment: Umm I feel like I'm missing something big. I download Sourcery on Windows, I open the IDE, but can't find any option for cross-compiling. Can you help me step by step? Is there maybe a way to just compile gcc and then move the gcc binary to the pi?

Comment: Compiling gcc and moving it to raspberry might be a bit more complex process, rather try http://rohitdureja.wordpress.com/2011/07/30/setting-up-codesourcery-gnu-toolchain-for-the-arm-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x-10-7/ link to get your tool chain running with IDE. Hope that the process might be same on Windows. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you've tagged this post as "yocto".
So the only thing I can advice you is using this wonderful tool :)
you don't want to compile your tools from your raspi, but from your killer linux machine :)

first, make sure you have all the prerequisists.
for fedora:

```
sudo yum install gawk make wget tar bzip2 gzip python unzip perl patch \
     diffutils diffstat git cpp gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel texinfo chrpath \
     ccache perl-Data-Dumper perl-Text-ParseWords perl-Thread-Queue socat
```

for ubuntu / debian:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk wget git-core diffstat unzip texinfo gcc-multilib \
 build-essential chrpath socat
```

then, you can get yocto from git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky -b daisy
```

then, you need to get the raspberrypi layer and its dependencies:

```
cd poky
git clone http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/meta-raspberrypi -b daisy
git clone git://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded -b daisy
```

then, setup the build environment:

```
source oe-init-build-env rpi-build
```

here rpi-build will be the name of the build directory, it can be whatever you want.
this will setup all the environment variables needed to use yocto, andmove you to the newly create build directory.

edit conf/bblayers.conf
and add the needed layers to BBLAYERS. it should look like something like this:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \                                                                 
  /path/to/poky/meta \                      
  /path/to/poky/meta-yocto \                
  /path/to/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \            
  /path/to/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \ 
  /path/to/poky/meta-raspberrypi \                            
"
```

then, edit conf/local.conf
set the MACHINE variabel to raspberrypi:

```
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi"
```

you can also tell yocto to generate deb files instead of the default rpms by changing:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
```

to:

```
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_deb"
```

in order to quickly have dpkg present in the build, just add the following line in your conf/local.conf

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL="dpkg"
```

and create a basic image:

```
bitbake rpi-basic-image
```

this will take some time.... a LOT of time in fact (yocto will generate the whole rootfilesystem, it will download the sources and compile them, will create deb packages for each of them, and will generate a flashable s image).

during that time I suggest you read the yocto documentation in order to understand how to add more software to the resulting image and / or customise it.
Explaining how yocto works can't just be an answer in stackoverflow you'll need to read the documentation and practice a little bit.

but the main thing to understand is that yocto provides receipes. Basically, a receipe describes how to get a packages and how to compile it.
a simple example of receipe can be found in:

```
meta/recipes-devtools/rpm/rpmresolve_1.0.bb
```

the good thing with yocto, is that you can easily add your own receipes.
layers provide supersets of receipes, they also allow customisation.
here, we added the raspberrypi layer in order to add support for the raspberry board.
the raspberry layer provides all the receipes needed to configure the kernel, and the bootloader etc...

once compilation is done, in order to flash the resulting sd image just do:

```
dd bs=4M if=/path/to/rpi-build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi/rpi-basic-image-raspberrypi.rpi-sdimg of=/dev/sd?
```

where "sd?" is your (unmounted) sdcard (think about saving it if needed)
plug back your sdcard to your raspi,
boot it.

in order to find out the raspi ip, you can scan your network for open ssh ports:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV YOU_SUBNET_ADDRESS/SUBNET_SIZE
```

example:

```
nmap -p 22 --open -sV 192.168.1.0/24


ssh root@RASPI-IP
```

and voila !

next time you'll need to build a new package, you can do:

```
bitbake package-name
```

and then just scp the resulting .deb file (from tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/PACKAGE_NAME/PACKAGE_VERSION/deploy-debs/armv6-vfp/PACKAGE.ipk) to the raspi and use dpkg to install it.
you can also create your own image based on rpi-basic-image and adding your own selection of packages.

Exmple with htop:

```
bitbake htop
scp ./tmp/work/armv6-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi/htop/1.0.3-r0/deploy-debs/armv6-vfp/htop_1.0.3-r0_armv6-vfp.deb root@myraspi
```

yocto will be very helpful to ease the cross compilation process for you.

sources:
https://github.com/djwillis/meta-raspberrypi
https://yoctoproject.org

kamou

Comment: OOPS, I just realised your are running a windows machine... You can use the Build Appliance to be able to use Yocto from windows, but it is not really recommanded... you should switch to linux. see https://www.yoctoproject.org/tools-resources/projects/build-appliance