# Minimal System: No gcc

Tags: gcc

I have a noob question. I have a minimal system(a headless linux) on my Raspberry Pi 3. I wanted to compile a C program. However I do not see the gcc binary. All I see is the libgcc_s.so library. How can I proceed with compilation. What do I need to "get" the gcc into the system.

Thanks.

Comment: sudo apt install gcc

Comment: Well, since I have a minimal system, I do not have apt tool. However my question is does libgcc_s.so has any relation to gcc?? Having this library, can I somehow get the executable?

Comment: No. But do you have raspbian?

Comment: No just a BusyBox on Rpi3. It is the Os of choice for our purpose.

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23933095/how-to-install-gcc-and-or-apt-on-embedded-linux-raspberry-pi#26791373 ?